# XML from Geocode Api Can't be Converted to XML by AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, google-maps, geocoding

AS3 code, badly written, I need to retrieve XML data from Google Maps Api and retrieve nodes/strings from it. Doesn't happen. I need to use the XML Data as a variable value, to then get the children of it and nodes in that child to then put them in an array (a bit like with my tweet XML data). This is my output:

```
RT @StonesGotStyle: Feeling terrible, darn you flu! This may be the only way to make me feel better! http://t.co/RJLEog6c8c So awesome! @OM…
Majulah Singapura
have the worst heyfever, and coming down with a flu whilst having guests round and I need to revise is the worst scenario **
London
2
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>country</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>United Kingdom</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>55.3780510</lat>
    <lng>-3.4359730</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>49.8669688</lat>
     <lng>-8.6493572</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>60.8565530</lat>
     <lng>1.7627096</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>34.5640831</lat>
     <lng>-8.6493572</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>60.9113448</lat>
     <lng>33.9165549</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
" to XML.
    at app::main/locate()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

And my code:

```
package app
{
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var geoReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
        public var geoLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        public var geoXml:XML = new XML();
        public var geoLocList:XMLList = new XMLList();
        public var geoLoc:Array = new Array();
        public function main():void
        {
            geoLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, locate);
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=flu&rpp=3&lang=en&geocode=55.378051,-3.435973,605mi");
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getTweets);
            loader.load(urlReq);
        }
        function getTweets( e:Event ):void
        {
            loadGeo("UK");
            if ( e.target.data )
            {
                var tweets = new Array(); var times = new Array();
                var twitterXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
                var tweetList:XMLList = twitterXML.children();
                var tweetItem:String;
                var placeItem:String;
                var tweet:Array = new Array();
                for (var i:int = 0; i < tweetList.length(); i++)
                {
                    tweetItem = tweetList[i].*::title;
                    placeItem = tweetList[i].*::location;
                    if( tweetItem && placeItem != "")
                    {
                    tweet = [tweetItem, placeItem];
                    tweets.push(tweet);
                    trace(tweets[tweets.length - 1][0]);
                    trace(tweets[tweets.length - 1][1]);
                    }
                }
                trace(tweets.length);
            }
        }
        function loadGeo(loc:String):void
        {
            geoReq = new URLRequest("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + loc + "&sensor=false");
            geoLoader.load(geoReq);
        }
        function locate(e:Event):void
        {
            geoXml = e.target.data;
            //geoLocList = geoXml.children();
            //geoLoc = [geoLocList[0].*::lat, geoLocList[0].*::lng];
            trace("located");
            trace(e.target.data);
            //trace(geoXml);
            trace("located");
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance, Kyle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you're getting back is a `String`, so you need to create a new XML object based off of that `String`.

In your `locate()` method change this line:

```
geoXml = e.target.data;
```

To:

```
geoXml = new XML(e.target.data);
```